# capture info from ID Token with Actions On Google?

Tags: actions-on-google, api-ai

I see that we can use the Account linking with Actions On Google to automatically signup users using the Google Sign-In ID token which provides info such as email and name.

Can we import that data into our own database so that we can contact the user in the future via email to make them aware of updates and new features?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is yes you can. You just need to explain it clearly on your T&C page and privacy policy page.